# How do I populate Stripe's description field on subscription charge?

Tags: perl, stripe-payments

I can populate [`Business::Stripe`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Business-Stripe/README.pod)'s description field for one off charges with the below code :

```
use Business::Stripe;    # Version 0.4

# Create Customer
my $customer = $stripe->api('post', 'customers',
    card        => $stripeToken,
    description => $username,
);

# Charge
my $charge = $stripe->api('post', 'charges',
    customer    => $customer,
    currency    => $currency,
    description => 'my description here no probs',
    amount      => $amount,
);
```

But when I create a customer a customer and assign them to a subscription plan I can't see how to populate the description of the charge made each billing period.

```
# Create Customer and subscribe to a plan
my $customer = $stripe->api('post', 'customers',
    card        => $stripeToken,
    description => 'description here is for the customer not the monthly charge',
    plan        => $plan
);
```

I want to be able to add a description to the charge that happens each billing period.

The API doesn't seem to show a way but the field is editable via the strie dashboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stripe is thinking about auto-populating the charge description on invoices, but that's not a feature that exists yet. In the meantime, once the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event occurs, you can get the charge ID from that event data. Then you can update the charge's description via the API:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_charge

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Now I know its not possible right now I can stop looking :)

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for the response. Because of your tutorials and answers here, I am loving Stripe. One question, do we have to still use this solution? Or did Stripe change the way things are done? Thanks.

Comment: @Greeso: as of Decembee 2017, this still seems to be the way to do it, seeing as `\Stripe\Subscription::create()` does not support any `description` argument.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert - Yes, I unfortunately realized this as well :( I hope Stripe fixes this